# Showing the user something while app is busy working?

Tags: windows-phone-7, camera

In my app I use the camera, and when the user takes a picture, my app encodes it to JPEG + various other operations. This takes a few seconds, but it results in an unresponsive UI while its working = bad user experience!

Is there any way to show the user something - perhaps a progressbar - while the app is working on the picture?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Whatever you show to the user is irrelevant if your processing is happening on the UI thread (more-or-less). You need to push your processing onto a background thread (perhaps by using the [`BackgroundWorker`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker%28v=VS.95%29.aspx)) and then the UI will be responsive enough to cope with showing progress to the user.

Comment: Okay, I've never tried that before, are you suggesting that the whole camera_completed should somehow be pushed to that, or just the processing I do in the event?

Comment: Just the processing. The `DoWork` handler for the `BackgroundWorker` is where you do your background processing. The `RunWorkerCompleted` handler is automatically marshalled back onto the originating thread (typically the UI thread).

Comment: Thanks, it's working now :) Now I just gotta find a decent way to display the progressbar.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at this url: [PerformanceProgressBar](http://www.windowsphonegeek.com/articles/WP7-PerformanceProgressBar-in-depth)

Note that the standard progressbar has issues (working on the UI-thread), but I think I remember reading that Microsoft shipped version 2 of some of the controls.

Regards,

M.

Comment: Yeah I've tried using the performanceprogressbar, but the app hangs when transitioning from the camera's page to the app's page. So it seems that when the camera / phone is working, other new threads cant start. Or maybe I just enable the progressbar at the wrong place.

Answer (score 0):

Advising PerformanceProgressBar as a matter of entertaining the user during a CPU-demanding activity (such as image processing) is a misunderstanding as this progress bar will consume more than 50% of the CPU resources and severely degrade the performance. You'll find the reason [here](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/showcase/WP7-Animations.aspx?msg=3811440#xx3811440xx). Plus the explanation how to do it correctly.